How to populate a Google Sheet cell with multiple values from data passed from HTML webpage to App Script
I have an HTML website which, when submitted, populates my Google Sheet using my existing App Script. This all works fine but the issue I'm stuck with is in my website, I have a table which allows multiple rows and each row has an input.

This is the data that's posted to my Google Sheet when submitted

Port Main Num=No&Porting Type=PRO&Range Holder=TO POPULATE&Maintain
DQ=No&Line Type=Multi&Associated Numbers=01111111111&Associated
Numbers Actions=Port&Associated Numbers=02222222222&Associated Numbers
Actions=Cease&Associated Numbers=01111122222&Associated Numbers
Actions=Port&Title=Mr&Initial=t&Surname=Test&Account
Number=01611111111&Company Name=Test Company&Building Name=&Address
Line 1=Address Line 1&Address Line 2=&Town or City=Town&Postcode=BB1
1BB&Porting Date=08/10/2024&Main Billing Number=01611111111

But when I check my Google Sheet it only populates with the last number entered (which I did expect)

As you can see from my data, I am passing all 3 numbers so I know I need a loop, but I can't find any relevant information online. The only help I can find is looping cells in the spreadsheet.
This is my current App Script code
const DATA_ENTRY_SHEET_NAME = "Sheet1";
const TIME_STAMP_COLUMN_NAME = "Date";
const REF_COLUMN_NAME = "Ref";
const CUST_EMAIL_COLUMN_NAME = "Email Address";
const PORTING_TIME_COLUMN_NAME = "Porting Time";


var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName(DATA_ENTRY_SHEET_NAME);

const doPost = (request = {}) => {
  const { postData: { contents, type } = {} } = request;
  var data = parseFormData(contents);
  appendToGoogleSheet(data);
  
 return ContentService.createTextOutput(contents).setMimeType(ContentService.MimeType.JSON);
};

function parseFormData(postData) {
  var data = [];
  var parameters = postData.split('&');
  for (var i = 0; i < parameters.length; i++) {
    var keyValue = parameters[i].split('=');
    data[keyValue[0]] = decodeURIComponent(keyValue[1]);
  }
  return data;
}

function appendToGoogleSheet(data) {
  if (TIME_STAMP_COLUMN_NAME !== "") {
    data[TIME_STAMP_COLUMN_NAME]=new Date();
  }

  if (sheet.getRange(sheet.getLastRow(), 2).getValue() !== 'Ref') {
    var ref = sheet.getRange(sheet.getLastRow(), 2).getValue().replace("Port-","");
    var ref = parseFloat(ref)+1
    data[REF_COLUMN_NAME]= 'Port-' + ref
  } else {
     data[REF_COLUMN_NAME]='Port-10000'
  }

  if (CUST_EMAIL_COLUMN_NAME !== "") {
    data[CUST_EMAIL_COLUMN_NAME]= 'test@test.co.uk';
  }

  if (PORTING_TIME_COLUMN_NAME !== "") {
    data[PORTING_TIME_COLUMN_NAME]= '10:00';
  }

  var headers = sheet.getRange(5, 1, 1, sheet.getLastColumn()).getValues()[0];
  var rowData = headers.map(headerFld => data[headerFld]);
  sheet.appendRow(rowData);
}


Would you be able to provide your sample sheet, with your initial output, and also your expected output so that we can further help you. You may use this anonymous sheet maker to create your reproducible example without your email being exposed.

Could you please share your complete code, including the HTML? This will help us identify the context for your answer.

The problem is in your parseFormData function. The line
data[keyValue[0]] = decodeURIComponent(keyValue[1]);

assigns a value to the keyValue[0] property, replacing any previous value that would exist if there are several form input fields with the same name attribute - as is your case.
So a possible solution is to check if there already is data with that name, in which case then append the new data to that property. This can be achieved with the ternary operator as follows:
data[keyValue[0]] = data[keyValue[0]] ?
  data[keyValue[0]].concat(', ', decodeURIComponent(keyValue[1])) :
  decodeURIComponent(keyValue[1]);

My example concatenates the strings with a ', ' separator. Depending on your desired result, you can change that to '\n' or whatever.
By the way, is there a reason you are using an array to output your data in this function? I believe an object is much more adapted here1. So here's my proposed modified function:


const postData = "Port Main Num=No&Porting Type=PRO&Range Holder=TO POPULATE&Maintain DQ=No&Line Type=Multi&Associated Numbers=01111111111&Associated Numbers Actions=Port&Associated Numbers=02222222222&Associated Numbers Actions=Cease&Associated Numbers=01111122222&Associated Numbers Actions=Port&Title=Mr&Initial=t&Surname=Test&Account Number=01611111111&Company Name=Test Company&Building Name=&Address Line 1=Address Line 1&Address Line 2=&Town or City=Town&Postcode=BB1 1BB&Porting Date=08/10/2024&Main Billing Number=01611111111";

function parseFormData(postData) {
  var data = {};  // <-- Changed this.
  var parameters = postData.split('&');
  for (var i = 0; i < parameters.length; i++) {
    var keyValue = parameters[i].split('=');
    data[keyValue[0]] = data[keyValue[0]] ?
        data[keyValue[0]].concat(', ', decodeURIComponent(keyValue[1])) :
      decodeURIComponent(keyValue[1]);
  }
  return data;
}

console.log(parseFormData(postData));



References

String.concat
Ternary operator


1An array is, in JavaScript, an object; that is exactly how you were using your data array in your function: adding "hidden" properties to the array.

Cheers worked great and I also made the change you did. The base code I used I'll be honest I got help with as I said I am completely new to app script so still finding my feet

You've got an unusual thing happening, in that you're using an empty array as the initial value for data, but you're treating it like an object. In JavaScript, an Array is just an object that has integer keys, but semantically it's a bit confusing.
The fundamental problem though, is that object keys are unique, so every time you set a property on the object to a particular value, you overwrite any existing value:
data[keyValue[0]] = decodeURIComponent(keyValue[1]);

I would suggest:

starting with an empty object, {} instead of an empty array [].
assume every parameter is multi-valued
make the value of every property on the object an array [] which semantically implies "a list of things", then update the array for each value of the same parameter

You can achieve this rather nicely with the function reduce, which is part of the array prototype. Reduce can take a bit of wrapping your head around, if you're new to it, but it's a really powerful tool, and worth the effort.
My reduce function looks like this:


const POST_DATA = 'Port Main Num=No&Porting Type=PRO&Range Holder=TO POPULATE&Maintain DQ=No&Line Type=Multi&Associated Numbers=01111111111&Associated Numbers Actions=Port&Associated Numbers=02222222222&Associated Numbers Actions=Cease&Associated Numbers=01111122222&Associated Numbers Actions=Port&Title=Mr&Initial=t&Surname=Test&Account Number=01611111111&Company Name=Test Company&Building Name=&Address Line 1=Address Line 1&Address Line 2=&Town or City=Town&Postcode=BB1 1BB&Porting Date=08/10/2024&Main Billing Number=01611111111'

function parseFormData(postData = POST_DATA) {
  const data = postData.split('&').reduce((acc, param) => {
    const [key, value] = param.split('=');
    return {
      ...acc,
      [key]: [...(acc[key] || []), decodeURIComponent(value)]
    }
  }, {});
  console.log(data);
  return data;
}

parseFormData();



If you don't want to bother with reduce and spread operators, and tricky little hacks for conditional inclusion in an array, you could just do this instead:


    const POST_DATA = 'Port Main Num=No&Porting Type=PRO&Range Holder=TO POPULATE&Maintain DQ=No&Line Type=Multi&Associated Numbers=01111111111&Associated Numbers Actions=Port&Associated Numbers=02222222222&Associated Numbers Actions=Cease&Associated Numbers=01111122222&Associated Numbers Actions=Port&Title=Mr&Initial=t&Surname=Test&Account Number=01611111111&Company Name=Test Company&Building Name=&Address Line 1=Address Line 1&Address Line 2=&Town or City=Town&Postcode=BB1 1BB&Porting Date=08/10/2024&Main Billing Number=01611111111'

    function parseFormData(postData = POST_DATA) {
      const data = {};
      for(parameter of postData.split('&')) {
        const [key, value] = parameter.split('=');
        data[key] = data[key] ?? []; // initialize to empty array, if it doesn't already exist;
        data[key].push(decodeURIComponent(value)); // push the new value into the array
      }
      return data;
    }

    console.log(parseFormData())



Now all your multi-valued query params are preserved as lists that can be handled in JavaScript without having to keep splitting and re-joining them.
You could handle that in several ways to get those values into your spreadsheet. You could:

use join(", ") or `join("\n") to just concatenate the strings before you write them to the sheet
You could write them into a separate sheet with a reference back to the row, like a foreign-key relationship in a database, if you wanted to preserve them as independently-referencable items in the spreadsheet

It depends what you're trying to accomplish.
